# Closure in JavaScript from CoderSchool

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I was doing some studying on CodeSchool. While watching a tutorial I was confused by an example. What they were trying to explain in the video was that closures created in loops won't bind until the last minute. The aim for this code was to take a name check for it in the array and return the name alone with its position(without the zero convention). Since closures don't bind till the last minute this code is returning `z 5`. I am confused why this code is returning a 5 and not a 4. The length of my array is 4 and the for loop stops before 4 because `i < passengerArray.length` which is the equivalent of `i < 4` therefore the last index checked should be `passengerArray[3]` which means my `(i+1)` should be 4 in the end and not 5. I hope that makes sense. This has been bothering me all day.

```
function assignTorpedo(name, passengerArray)
{var torpedoassignment; 
for(var i = 0; i < passengerArray.length; i++){
    if(passengerArray[i] == name){
        torpedoAssignment = function(){
            console.log(name + " " + (i+1));
        };
    }
}
return torpedoAssignment;
}

var give = assignTorpedo("z",["z","a","b","c"]);

give();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop ends when the test condition **fails**. Why does it fail? Because `i` is **not** less than 4; it's **equal to** 4.  Thus, in the `console.log()` output you see 5.

Also, the statement

> closures created in loops won't bind until the last minute.

is a strange way of describing how things work. As soon as the name is found in the array, the variable is assigned a reference to the constructed function. When `assignTorpedo` returns that value, the closure exists. In the closure, the value of the variable "i" is already 4.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am still confused, wont the for loop check the second statement in the for loop `i < passengerArray.length` for 4 < 4 and say "hm, not true. I will not run the code in the for-loop again." Sorry for my simplistic way of asking these questions. I am still learning. For example how is this different from `for(var i = 0; i < 4;i++){console.log(i)}`

Comment: @theamateurdataanalyst Yes, that's right. But at that point `i` is already set to 4. Note that your `console.log()` call doesn't happen until the function is called later, *after* the loop is finished. That's what makes it different than doing a `console.log()` *inside* the loop.

Comment: @theamateurdataanalyst It's important to note that when the function is constructed, it is **not** the case that the value of "i" is frozen for that function. Instead, the function has a reference to "i" that is persistent. It's like there's a shell around the function where "i" lives, and that shell continues to exist when the constructed function is returned and when the function is later called. The variable "i" is preserved as it was when `assignTorpedo()` exited, and *not* simply when that function was created.

Comment: Thanks Pointy. I think I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

The following statement increments `i` by 1 after each pass through the loop. So, after the fourth iteration `i` will be increased by one and tested against the condition again, and then it will fail.

```
var arr = ["z","a","b","c"];

for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    console.log( i );
}

console.log( i );
```

Answer (score 0):

The For loop finishes when condition "i < passengerArray.length" being violated which i equals 4 at that time.

then console.log(name + " " + (4 + 1)));

**Power Tip:**

From one of my lecturers in uni,

"Think a "For" loop like a 'While' loop like this"

```
i = 0;
while (i < passengerArray.length)
{
    ...............
    i++;
}
```